# Does youtube prevent multitasking?

Tags: operating-system, multitasking

Users are unable to run Youtube in background on mobile operating systems. I wonder if we can conclude that Youtube does not support multitasking on mobile devices?

Comment: This is way too broad and doesn't really lend itself to Stackoverflow's question-with-definitive-answer format.

Comment: I don't want to know what to do with it. I'm just interested in its relationship to multitasking. Is it truly a multitasking affair or not?

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad and iPhone things in general do not run in the background at all. You have to take additional steps to do so. This is to conserve power.

Comment: I don't want to know what to do with it. I'm just interested in its relationship to multitasking. Is it truly a multitasking affair or not?

Comment: The application developer chooses not to override the normal prohibition on running in the background. So apps do run the background, such as maps. It makes no sense to play videos in the background when they cannot be seen.